# Java How Write File TotalSize

Tags: java

Hello  end row is missing. How ı can write total size of file thank you sorry for my bad english.

```
table.setOnDragDropped(evt -> {
   //Dosyanın Yolunu yazar
 System.out.println(evt.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::getAbsolutePath).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
//Dosyanın adını yazar
System.out.println(evt.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::getName).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
  //
System.out.println(evt.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::getTotalSpace).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: For a `File f` with `f.length()`